# Hyper V 2012 and SQL Cluster Live migration

Tags: hyper-v, storage, live-migration

I've been doing allot of searching and even asked around here at the office without a good answer.

I would like to know, within Server 2012 R2 Hyper V, can you or can not do a storage migration of a shared drive like a quorum drive.

Allow me elaborate, 
So what they want to do is to stand up a Hyper V environment, build a Virtual SQL Cluster.
But before they do, they want to know if they can Live Migrate the shared storage from the SQL cluster, like the quorum drive without any downtime.
I know for a fact VMware cannot do this, so thats why we exploring Hyper V solution.

Learned with Server 2012 R2 you can do shared nothing migrations, but doesnt really hit the point that i'm looking for.

Please don't ask why they not pursuing a SQL cluster without shared storage, they just wont do that.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Adian Finn explains the limitations of guest clusters quite well here: http://www.aidanfinn.com/?p=14936

The answer is no, as of Server 2012R2, you cannot live storage migrate the guest shared VHDX.  You can move everything else still, but not the shared one.

You also cant expand the shared drive online or use Hyper-V replica.

It makes sense really - coordinating the transfer without the guest cluster freaking out would be quite difficult.